# Getting undefined variable "row"

Tags: php, mysql

Getting error

> Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp\htdocs\ipo\details.php on line 65.

I am using php with sql.

```
<?php
    include 'header.php';
    include 'navbarmain.php';
    $count = 0;

    $PageID = (int) trim($_GET['id']);
    if($PageID == 0){
        //you can show error or redirect to other page
    }

    $mysqli = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='{$PageID}' LIMIT 1");
    foreach($mysqli as $row){
        $count++;
        if($count == 0) { // three items in a row
            $count = 0;
        }
    }

?>

<a href="#">
  <img class="media-object" src="<?php echo $row["filename"]; ?>" alt="...">
  <span class="nsbs">NSE / BSE</span>
</a>
```

Comment: `LIMIT 1` will only give back one row, at most. Not sure what you mean by `three items in a row` nor the `foreach` loop, or the `$count`.

Comment: If `$mysqli` is not iterable (because of an error an empty result set) then `$row` will not be defined.  If `id` is the primary key, then you don't need `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Either set a default value for when there is no row in the result set, or write your html inside of the `foreach(){}`.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to write filename outside the loop .That might be the reason for your error. Please try below code

```
<?php
    include 'header.php';
    include 'navbarmain.php';
    $count = 0;

    $PageID = (int) trim($_GET['id']);
    if($PageID == 0){
        //you can show error or redirect to other page
    }

    $mysqli = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE id='{$PageID}' LIMIT 1");
    foreach($mysqli as $row){
        $count++;
        if($count == 0) { // three items in a row
            $count = 0;
        }

    ?>
    <a href="#">
      <img class="media-object" src="<?php echo $row["filename"]; ?>" alt="...">
      <span class="nsbs">NSE / BSE</span>
    </a>

     <?php
    }

?>
```